# How to execute Altova Mapforce Console application as window service?

Tags: windows, console-application, altova

Altova Mapforce create the console application now i want to call that console application on window service Onstart(). how to pass the parameters of altova mapforce console application from Window service.

Altova Mapforce :http://www.altova.com/mapforce.html

I want the console application behavior as Window service.

If any one please reply me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I found the answer of this question.

I create on custom class. augment that class into auto generate code at run time.Change the SPL directory.  I am working in c# code. So I change the below file in spl directory

```
C:\Program Files\Altova\MapForce2012\spl\spl\cs\MapForce\AlgorithmGroup.cs 

and 

C:\Program Files\Altova\MapForce2012\spl\spl\cs\MapForce\MapForce2005.csproj
```

and call run() of auto generated code into class.

If any one want more help then Please contact me here.I will share whole source code.
Thank you all.

Comment: I need help. I want to change SPL code that is generating C# code. I simply want to keep reference to the current Altova.Mapforce.IMFEnumerator inner class's current object. I will be happy just creating a global reference that gets set in every IMFEnumerator class.